# Discord.js V13 dont know how to check if a user ID is in the current guild

Tags: discord.js

I have been trying to check if a certain user ID exists in the current guild,

I have been looking at countless stack overflow questions and documentations hoping i could find the answer but nothing I try actually works.

i use Discord.js V13 with the latest node.js version

```js
const server = client.guilds.fetch( message.guild.id );
if ( !server.member(args[0]) ) return commandFailed('a user with this ID does not exist');
// args[0] contains the userID
```

could someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**: `fetch` returns a promise, you must handle that promise. However, you don't need to fetch the server since the server is already accessible through `message.guild`.

**Second**: `Guild#member()` is deprecated, try fetching the member directly and checking if a member returned.

I'll be using [Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) for this example, make sure you're inside an Async function.

```js
// const server = await client.guilds.fetch(message.guild.id); is not needed

const server = message.guild;

const member = await server.members.fetch(args[0]);

if (!member) return commandFailed('a user with this ID does not exist');
```

Comment: thank you this worked. but now i have the problem that this piece of code `memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get( args[0] );` returns undefined, which is weird since this works perfectly with getting the mentioned user's id

Comment: `.get()` checks the cache, returns undefined if whatever you're trying to access is *not cached*, it's best to always use `fetch()` and not rely on the cache.Whenever a member is mentioned they are instantly cached which is why you are able to use `get()` on them

Comment: when i change get() to fetch() i get this error `TypeError: message.guild.members.cache.fetch is not a function`. is there any reason for this?

Comment: last question. is there a way to get the data without getting a promise? i am not very good at implementing promises as i have no idea how it works...

Comment: No, it's data retrieved through API calls. If you want to fully learn Discord.JS you will need to get the hang of handling promises. They may be intimidating but study, watch a tutorial or 2 and you'll get the hang of it

Comment: I have successfully managed to resolve the promise and get the data. But the promise is resolved AFTER the rest of the code is done. Is there a way to make the promise resolve immediately. Because I am currently using functions to call the rest of the code after the promise is resolved, and I don't like that "cheaty" method.

Comment: If you have a new issue consider posting a new question

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53284678/11943314)** thread, which explains exactly what you want:

```
let guild = client.guilds.get('guild ID here'),
  USER_ID = '123123123';

if (guild.member(USER_ID)) {
  // there is a GuildMember with that ID
}
```

Comment: i have already tried that thread and it returns this error. 

TypeError: client.guilds.get is not a function. could be because that thread is from 2018

Comment: What about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65853663/11943314